# kendo ui grid loading indicator not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I am using kendo grid in my html page and every thing working perfectly but one issue i am facing when page loads and i send request to get data it takes 1 or 2 seconds meanwhile grid should show loading indicator as we can see in [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy) . This is what i am doing

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: api/getdata,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            headers: { 'ccode': compCode },
            async: false,
            data: '?&tableName=' + table + '&userId=' + userId + '&fromDate=' + dateFrom + '&toDate=' + dateto + '&isSearchForClient=' + true,
            success: function (result) {
                var data = [];
                if (result) {
                    result = result.replace(/&/g, "'");
                    var jsonResult = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(result));
                    for (var i = 0; i < jsonResult.length; i++) {
                        data.push({ Log: jsonResult[i]["Log"], TransactionId: jsonResult[i]["TransactionId"] });
                    }
                    var grid = $("#logs").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            data: data,
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    fields: {
                                        TransactionId: { type: "string" },
                                        Log: { type: "string" }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            pageSize: 10
                        },
                        height: 405,
                        scrollable: true,
                        detailInit: detailInit,
                        detailExpand: function (e) {
                            this.collapseRow(this.tbody.find(' > tr.k-master-row').not(e.masterRow));
                        },
                        pageable: {
                            input: true,
                            numeric: false
                        },
                        columns: [
                            { field: 'Log', title: "Audit Logs", encoded: true }]
                    });
                    //grid.dataSource.read();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why should it show it? As far as I can see, you are  loading the data using ajax and when finished loading is when you create the grid. Is that right?

Comment: yes @OnaBai you are right ....should i delete this question or need to answer it anyway

Comment: Well, the answer is that either you do the ajax from inside the `dataSource.transport.read` or you should do the "loading" yourself and remove it in the `success`. Do you know how or do you need me to change your code and show you how?

Comment: I know how to do that , but just asking about this question because you pointed me the issue and now its ok .